# Is it possible to use DependencyProperty in a WPF Browser Application?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, xbap

I am new with WPF, I am trying to change one of my applications form windows application to a browser application. In browser applications we use pages instead of windows. So I wonder if I can still use dependency properties. Here is my code in the WPF Windows Application:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KinectSensorManagerProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(
           "KinectSensorManager",
           typeof(KinectSensorManager),
           typeof(MainWindow),
           new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager
    {
        get { return (KinectSensorManager)GetValue(KinectSensorManagerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KinectSensorManagerProperty, value); }
    }
```

Therefore, can I use the same code in a browser application? And if not what is the substitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that XBAP doesn't support `DependencyProperties`, you can visit this  [link](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/28/comparing-wpf-applications-and-xbap-whats-the-difference/)

Comment: The only reason is that it is in System.Windows namespace... I tried to use the name space so I could use it, but I cannot use the GetValue and SetValue, do I need to add something else for those?